# Django Form sending only File field

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-models

Hello guys i am a rather new to Django and Python as well.

Using Django version 1.8
and python ver 2.7.6

want to update the fields of a form into the DB,
so would like to send all of them at the same time.
right now the issue dwells in the fact that it only uploads the image
into the server updating the path into the db too.. ***which is OK***

However all of the others fields which are not "File" remain ignored...so are not inserted into the db nor received as parameters in the view method.

*have to mention that for example purposes i am just adding description field.*

This is the structure.
based on:

**Models,
Views,
Forms,
Html**

**Models:**

```
from django.db import models
from decimal import Decimal
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
# Create your models here.
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    body = models.TextField()
    time = models.DateTimeField()

class ProfileImage(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='profile/%Y/%m/%d')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

---

**Forms:**

```
from django import forms

class ProfileImageForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.FileField(label='Select a profile Image')
    description = forms.CharField(required=True)
```

---

**Views:**

```
class ProfileImageView(FormView):
    template_name = 'upload.html'
    form_class = ProfileImageForm
    def form_valid(self,form): 
        profile_image = ProfileImage(
            image=self.get_form_kwargs().get('files')['image']), description=self.get_form_kwargs().get('files')['description'])
        if profile_image.is_valid():
          profile_image.save()
          #self.id = profile_image.id
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('profile_image', kwargs={'pk': self.id})

    class ProfileDetailView(DetailView):
        model = ProfileImage
        template_name = 'upload.html'
        context_object_name = 'image'


    class ProfileImageIndexView(ListView):
        model = ProfileImage
        template_name = 'upload.html'
        context_object_name = 'images'
        queryset = ProfileImage.objects.all()
```

---

**html:**

```
<html>
<head>
  Upload Picture
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
<form action="{% url "profile_image_upload" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

i have just tried modifying the class ProfileImageView by passing the parameter "description"
just like this:

profile_image = ProfileImage(
            image=self.get_form_kwargs().get('files')['image']), description=self.get_form_kwargs().get('files')['description'])

It shows the following error:

```
SyntaxError at /blog/upload/
invalid syntax (views.py, line 97)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/upload/
Django Version: 1.8
Exception Type: SyntaxError
Exception Value:    
invalid syntax (views.py, line 97)
Exception Location: /home/enigmathor/testPythweb/testPythweb/urls.py in <module>, line 3
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/enigmathor/testPythweb',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
Server time:    Mon, 22 Dec 2014 00:54:23 +0000
```

Have tried many other ways like adding request parameter into the form valid method in order to take the request.POST parameters later.

like this:

```
def form_valid(self,form,request):
```

The issue with the little code above is that it shows that there is no request parameters being sent.

***Please some help will really appreciate it. Thanks in advance***

Comment: Django 1.8 is still under development, consider going back to 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

Finally it worked!
It did not work because at the very beginning in the Views method **form_valid** i was getting the parameter "Description" in a wrong way.

it was like this:

> ```
> def form_valid(self,form): 
>     profile_image = ProfileImage(
>         image=self.get_form_kwargs().get('files')['image']), description=self.get_form_kwargs().get('files')['description'])
>     if profile_image.is_valid():
>       profile_image.save()
>       #self.id = profile_image.id
>     return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
> ```

So the issue was the line:

```
description=self.get_form_kwargs().get('files')['description']
```

it should be :

```
description=self.get_form_kwargs().get('data')['description']
```

cause was letting Django to expect the second parameter as a "**`file`**" type
when it was "**`data`**" type.

Hope it helps to others dealing as beginners with the framework.

***Now it works.***

**Cheers.-**